why do junction trees need to be without cycles?
I am studying the junction tree message passing algorithm for bayesian inference and do not understand why junction trees need to be without cycles. All I know is that it is needed for "efficient inference".
Does anyone know the answer? Thanks!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_tree_algorithm
